# Ubuntu install libcairo-dev dependency error

Tags: r, dependencies, ubuntu-14.04, cairo, apt-get

I try to install gdtools in R in ubuntu 14.04 64bit, but R studio compained that C

```
onfiguration failed because cairo was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libcairo-dev (Debian, Ubuntu)
```

After running  `sudo apt-get install libcairo-dev`, I got the following error

```
  Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
    requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
    distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
    or been moved out of Incoming.
    The following information may help to resolve the situation:

    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     libcairo2-dev : Depends: libcairo2 (= 1.13.0~20140204-0ubuntu1) but 1.13.0~20140204-0ubuntu1.1 is to be installed
                     Depends: libcairo-gobject2 (= 1.13.0~20140204-0ubuntu1) but 1.13.0~20140204-0ubuntu1.1 is to be installed
                     Depends: libfontconfig1-dev (>= 2.2.95) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libfreetype6-dev (>= 2.1.10) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libxrender-dev (>= 0.6) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libpixman-1-dev (>= 0.22.0) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libxext-dev but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libglib2.0-dev but it is not going to be installed
    E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So what should I do to solve this or find out the direction to move on?
Thanks for the suggestion about mixed ppa, but where could I find the mixed PPA and remove that?

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolve this issue

First I purged my teamviewer  "`sudo aptitude purge teamviewer:101`"

since libcairo2-dev depends on libcairo2, and my version of libcairo2 could be found by

apt-cache policy libcairo2, i found it is ***1.1 instead of ***1, so I downgrade that to be "`apt-get install libcairo2=*****1`", now it works.

Now gdtools could be installed in R!